# standard canonical formats for representing graph/network data in XML/ JSON and API to traverse

Tags: java, xml, json, graph

Is there any standard canonical formats for representing graph/network data ( example is your facebook or linkedin network) in XML/ JSON and API to access them ? In our current system graphs are represented in our Java based environment as Java MAP of maps. The difference in our system is that we need support for multiple graph types ( unlike facebook graphs where graph type is just a friend ).

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you mean different types of nodes within one graph or multiple graphs with one specific node type (e.g. colleague) per graph?

Answer (score 1):

Graphviz is neither XML nor JSON but it is an open format with renderers (API) for many platforms

Answer (score 1):

XML or JSON can be used to represent objects that reference other objects and that reference can be viewed as an edge in your graph. But to parse your graph as xml is probably inefficient.  There are databases specifically designed for this kind of data. Check out [neo4J](http://neo4j.org/)

The internal representation of the graph would be then delegated to the database and people have been working on this for years, so I would expect the representation to be efficient and performant. There may be some export to xml features that the database provides.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [NetJSON](http://netjson.org/), in particular the [NetworkGraph JSON object](http://netjson.org/rfc.html#rfc.section.4) and its [JSON-Schema](http://netjson.org/rfc.html#NetworkGraph-schema).

There's also a javascript visualizer implementation named [netjsongraph.js](https://github.com/interop-dev/netjsongraph.js).